# I'm having a trouble with for loop and input in python

Tags: arrays, for-loop, input

```
n=int(input("enter amount of values : "))
a=[]
for i in range (n):
 a[i]=int(input("number: "))
```

I don't know why python does some bad things happen around there can someone explain or show correct way.

That doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can use `append` to append thing on list.

Code:

```
n=int(input("enter amount of values : "))
a=[]
for i in range (n):
    a.append(int(input("number: ")))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
enter amount of values : 5
number: 3
number: 6
number: 2
number: 10
number: 6
[3, 6, 2, 10, 6]
```